# route 53 mixed routing policy

Tags: amazon-route53, failover

I need to configure a route 53 mixed routing policy.
It should act this way.

Lets say you have 2 servers (ip4 202.202.202.91 ip4 202.202.202.92):

I need to create Weighted Routing that 70% of calls go to 202.202.202.91 and 30% to 202.202.202.92. 
On top of that I need to create Failover Routing that says that if and of the servers fails a health check the the other gets 100% of the traffic until the failed resource recovers.

I can't find how to do this, and as this is production env I don't want to mess up. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You dont need to face it. when you consider 50 - 50 it's done , your traffic is balanced by default and when P1 is down all the trafic will go over P2 But......

If you can go one step more far an design a failover for whole production it's interesting

P1 fails , P2 Works 
P1 & P2 fail 
So Failover happens

The problem is the lmitation in Route53 records

You can not have a mix of policies on a domain set name so you need to create Two ones , The First on as failover and the second level as Weight Policy style.

Have a look on re:invent 2014 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9y-T7mQVxs